# Avoid a property from body of Angular Resource POST request

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am creating an angular resource as follows.

```
var Book = $resource(baseUrl + 'v1/users/:username/books/:id', {
        username: '@username'
        id: '@bookId'
      });
```

I am sending a `POST` call using `save()` as follows.
Book.save({username:'testuser', bookId:1, show: true})

This generates a URL properly

```
v1/users/testuser/books/1
```

But it sends `username`,`id` in body along with `show:true` which I want to avoid. How to avoid `username`,`id` in body?

Comment: include show parameter in the URL. However, if doing POST, it's better not to put data parameters in URL. I read somewhere that parameters to URL and body should not be mixed together, like in your case, I forgot the reason why parameters in URL and body should not be mixed.

Comment: Agreed. But I am using an API which provided URI like this. So somehow I have to manage same using resource.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how, I acheived it. I used transformRequest property of actions and deleted unnecessary properties.

```
var Book = $resource(baseUrl + 'v1/users/:username/books/:id', {
        username: '@username'
        id: '@bookId'
      }, {
      customSave: {
         method: 'POST',
         transformRequest: function(body) {
            delete body.username;
            delete body.id;
            return angular.toJSON(body);
         }
      }
});
```

Comment: This solved my problem too! Thanks :) But is there a cleaner way to achieve this?